# Can PostgreSQL COPY read CSV from a remote location?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I've been using JDBC with a local Postgres DB to copy data from CSV files into the database with the Postgres COPY command. I use Java to parse the existing CSV file into a CSV format matches the tables in the DB. I then save this parsed CSV to my local disk. I then have JDBC execute a COPY command using the parsed CSV to my local DB. Everything works as expected.
Now I'm trying to perform the same process on a Postgres DB on a remote server using JDBC. However, when JDBC tries to execute the COPY I get

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open file "C:\data\datafile.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

Am I correct in understanding that the COPY command tells the DB to look locally for this file? I.E. the remote server is looking on its C: drive (doesn't exist).

If this is the case, is there anyway to indicate to the copy command to look on my computer rather than "locally" on the remote machine? Reading through the copy documentation I didn't find anything that indicated this functionality.

If the functionality doesn't exist, I'm thinking of just populating the whole database locally then copying to database to the remote server but just wanted to check that I wasn't missing anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use JDBC, the best solution for you is to use the PostgreSQL COPY API
http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Otherwise (as already noted by others) you can use \copy from psql which allows accessing the local files on the client machine

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was unaware that this class existed. I am going to implement it in my Parsing/Importing program. To handle data in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Create your sql file as follows on your client machine

```
COPY testtable (column1, c2, c3) FROM STDIN WITH CSV;
1,2,3
4,5,6
\.
```

Then execute, on your client

psql -U postgres -f /mylocaldrive/copy.sql -h remoteserver.example.com

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did (in some form) since I ultimately already had the table created on my local machine. Going forward I'm going to use the API listed below.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the `COPY` command can only be used to read locally (either from stdin or from file) from the machine where the database is running.

You could make a shell script where you run you the java conversion, then use [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-psql.html) to do a `\copy` command, which reads from a file on the *client* machine.

Comment: COPY can read "FROM STDIN" -- it doesn't have to read a file from disk, per se.

Comment: @FrankFarmer Updated per your comment.